# Interacting w/ Subscriber Content via StackExchange API in Commercial Applications

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, api, licensing, terms-of-service

I've read the **API Terms of Use** and **The [Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service#attribution)** and just wanted to confirm that my understanding is correct:

Subscriber content **can** be used inside of a publicly accessible commercial applications so long as the attribution rules of the Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike license are followed?

For clarity, this is not the same question as this:
[Stack Exchange for commercial use](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67501/stack-exchange-for-commercial-use)

Comment: I think you are allowed to use any information in a commercial application, but you have to follow CC BY-SA 3.0 license.